# Beamer navigation bars to show only \subsubsections and \subsubsubsections

Tags: beamer, navigation

I need to customize my navigation bars in the following manner:

1. Subsubsection title shows up in navigation bars where section title are usually placed
2. A new command `\subsubsubsection` is defined
3. Title of the `\subsubsubsection` shows up where where subsection titles are usually placed.

This presentation would not use `\section` and `\subsection`. In effect I need to map two commands to take their place. The reason why I need this is that I am utilizing same slides via `\input{}` for two different scenarios. In one presentation I don't wish them to show up in navigation bars as they are a minor part of a huge presentation, but in the other they would be the only content and sectioning should be visible in navigation bars. Here is my minimal (non) working example. I usually use Warsaw theme, but hopefully the solution would be theme agnostic.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Section} %This should show up in navigation bar in a place where the section title is usually placed

\begin{frame}{Sample Slide I}
 Content 
\end{frame}

\subsubsubsection{Subsection} %This should show up in navigation bar in a place where the subsection title is usually placed

\begin{frame}{Sample Slide I}   
Content 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design of `beamer` discourages `\subsubsection` use and is built around a formal structure of `\section`/`\subsection`/(`\subsubsection`) (*i.e.* subsections have to be part of sections). Indeed, support for `\subsubsection`s is partial at best. There is no support for `\subsubsubsection` (not a standard LaTeX command anyway: `\paragraph` is the name for this concept in the base classes but this is quite deliberately not defined in `beamer`).

Where the source has to use `\subsubsection` and `\subsubsubsection`, I'd therefore go with redirecting these to `\section` and `\subsection`, respectively:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\let\subsubsection\section
\let\subsubsubsection\subsection
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{A}

\begin{frame}{Sample Slide I}
 Content 
\end{frame}

\subsubsubsection{AA}

\begin{frame}{Sample Slide I}   
Content 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The `\let` block could be set up conditionally if required, of of course you could give them custom names (`\mysection` or similar).

Comment: The \let command was exactly what I was looking for to map one level of sectioning to another. I will use \part and \subsubsection and map them onto \section and \subsection respectively. That way the same slides could be plugged into larger presentations via \input command without influencing the navigation bars. Thanks!